# Help understanding chip function

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design

Can't find a Datasheet for this charging ic from an iPhone 6. Hopefully someone can explain its function to me.

Things I'm confused about; Does it take USB power and convert it to both vcc_main and vbatt? Or does it output vcc_main and vbatt is also an input to the chip?

What's q1403's role?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's incredibly hard to make anything out on that screenshot. Please try and provide a better one, or a link to the file that it is in.

From general battery charger principles though:

> Does it take USB power and convert it to both vcc_main and vbatt?

Yes.

> Or does it output vcc_main and vbatt is also an input to the chip?

Yes.

Confused yet?

If there is USB power then that USB power goes to VCC_MAIN and is used to charge the battery through VBATT.

If there is no USB power then VBATT is used to provide power to VCC_MAIN.

Comment: That helps. So if there is no USB power does vbatt go directly to vcc_main or would it go to vcc_main and the ic chip as well? And when USB power is present charging the battery does the battery stop providing power to vcc_main?

Comment: It looks like Q1403 might be linking the battery direct to VCC_MAIN. When there is no other power the current flows through the body diode to VCC_MAIN which then starts the system running, which means the charge management chip gets power and then turns on Q1403 to bypass the body diode.

Comment: When there is USB power the CM chip turns the FET off, and with VMAIN higher than VBATT it remains reverse biased.

Comment: So with USB power vbatt only gets a charge from the chip and doesn't provide any power to the system at all because q1403 blocks it?

Comment: I think that is how it works, but it's hard to be sure. In general you shouldn't power a system from a battery at the same time you're charging it, which that arrangement looks to do properly.

Comment: If the chip turns the q1403 fet off during charging, wouldn't power from vbatt still make its way to vcc_main via the body diode of q1403?

Comment: Only if VCC_MAIN were at a lower voltage than VBATT, in which case the battery won't be being charged anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little stumped on that body diode thing, how wouldn't any power get through it from vbatt to vcc_main? I can't get past that (in my mind) it's essentially a wire connecting the two

Comment: If VBATT has a higher voltage than VCC_MAIN (or VCC_MAIN has no power) then the diode conducts and VCC_MAIN gets power. The battery is then powering the system. If VCC_MAIN is a higher voltage than the battery then the diode is reverse biased and does not conduct.

Comment: Ooh geesh I complicated it for no reason lol sorry about that. Makes sense when vcc_main is higher than it blocks the diode from letting power pass because it'll have a high voltage on its cathode

Comment: One other thing, is VDD the same as vcc? Or is VDD bucked by the switching pins to make vcc_main?

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing the rest of the circuit. Conceptually, though, VDD is the Drain Voltage, VCC is the Collector Voltage - the exact same thing but the first is for CMOS and the second for TTL (FET vs BJT).

Comment: Ah I ask because VDD pins from the ic are tied into the vcc_main line and then the switching pins from the chip tie into that line in the middle so I'm trying to understanding whether the bucking is happening to VDD to create vcc. I imagined that USB voltage would be bucked but that voltage has its own pin